# System of second order lineal differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system:

$x'' = \alpha^2 y - x $

$y'' = x- y $

I have no idea how can I start. Please give me some hint.

Comment: The system is linear and with constant coefficients. Therefore look for solutions in the form $x=x_0e^{\lambda t}$, $y=y_0e^{\lambda t}$. This will give a homogeneous linear system for $x_0$, $y_0$ which has nontrivial solutions only if $\lambda$ satisfies certain 4th order algebraic equation. Another (essentially equivalent) possibility: express $x$ from the 1st equation and get scalar 4th order linear ODE with constant coefficients for $y$.

Comment: Could you explain how to get the 4th order linear OD with constant coefficients for y? (I like that second aproach)

Comment: E.g. from the 2nd equation you have $x=y''+y$, hence $x''=y''''+y''$. Substituting this into the 1st equation, we have $$y''''+2y''+(1-\alpha^2)y=0.$$